# Function argument already initialized in function declaration C++

Tags: c++, function, parameters

So  here's my question in the function declaration there is an argument and it is already initialized to a certain value. What are the procedures to call this function and use that default value, or is it just a way to document code, telling other programmers what you expect them to use as a value for the parameter? Thank you.

```
enum File
{
    XML = 0,
    PDF = 1,
};

Char *SetSection(const File = XML);
```

Comment: You may also use this with multiple parameters. But in that case, if you provide an default value for parameter _N_, you must also provide default values for all subsequent parameter. The caller then has to provide at least _N_ - 1 arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, simply calling `SetSection` with no parameters will do.

```
SetSection();
```

The above call gets translated (for lack of a better term) to:

```
SetSection(XML);
```

Comment: That exactly what my question was, awesome that is an interesting feature that I never knew about.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the function can be called without parameters in which case the default value, XML, will be used.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `File` is a [default argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument). Calling `SetSection()` without arguments will set the `File` argument to the default value specified in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
SetSection();
```

It will call SetSection(XML) instead.
This is why the optional parameters have to be at the end of all parameters. If you don't provide enough parameters, it will use the default.

Answer (score 0):

XML is the standard parameter.
You can call it with `SetSection();` (But `SetSection(XML)` or `SetSection(PDF)` are valid, too).

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the declaration is a default argument value.

If you call `SetSection();` it is the same as calling `SetSection(XML);`

You can also call `SetSelection(PDF);` or use any other valid parameter to override the default.

You may also be seeing the result of an incremental development which started with the function having no parameter and calls to the function scattered throughout the code.  Then the alternative file type of PDF was introduced, but the prototype was changed to have a default value, which meant not having to change the existing call site.